# facebook bot - manipular url de imagens e arquivos anexados

Tags: node.js, api, facebook, bots

When sending a media type in facebook chat to a page that has a bot, I get the following response:

```
"recipient":{
   sender: { id: 'xxxx' },
   recipient: { id: 'xxxx' },
   timestamp: xxx,
  },
  "message":{
    "attachment":{
      "type":"image", 
      "payload":{
        "url":"https://lookaside.fbsbx.com/ig_messaging_cdn/?asset_id=2608864215911984&signature=AbykSEBb24Mq3HE0VzWv_XLb9klY3_7hiZauQp_DxjPbHGbEz_-N4r7Rf_7dxNM2v3yzzy0sIGvKFuiFxvCrvVAybrBa5omgAADBhtHnJMJk3TMqGnmrlIa5mmnaJ1nfQSFT1q0hQrTyVzl81gxGEOEl5AFwzVINKWeY_J-_0Oxb1qxHOrjnUgdFQNS_rGLa4QiNs0wkRk9OXOHlVtEy5sFxUqPY7Q"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

how can i get the filename + the mime type? or how can I download this file by this type of url?

I tried to download but the file is corrupted

Comment: _"I tried to download but the file is corrupted"_ - when I request that URL in my browser, I get an image containing the character "W". If you try to download it using server-side script or similar, Facebook might have restrictions on that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL in `attachment.payload.url` property is publicly accessible. Therefore, you can download the file server-side. Since you only need to find out the filename and MIME type, you can perform only a [HEAD request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD) since all data you need are in the headers, notably, for this file:

```http
content-disposition: inline;filename=image-2608864215911984
content-type: image/jpeg
```

(Obtained with `curl -I`)

Mind that you probably won't receive the original filename, as this information is not provided from Facebook's CDN. If this is a file you uploaded via the [attachment upload API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/attachment-upload-api), you could infer the filename from the URL provided on upload.

Comment: Really.
Get the mime-type Got it from the url through the header of the GET method.
the most interesting thing is that now I can download it even without informing the mime-type of the file. Thank you very much